# I’m doing something wrong when closing and/or opening my meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong, but I know I must be missing something.

Let’s say I create a new app. I start mongo dB. I get some data put into my app. Everything’s working. When I’m done I close my browser and close my terminal. When I want to resume working on my app, I open the terminal, I cd into my app directory, and hit meteor as usual, but it gives me an error on startup. In order for it to work, I have to run meteor reset then meteor and it starts the app, but I’ve lost my data.

I’m kind of a rookie all around. Any explanations and hand-holding would be warmly accepted.

you can see below, I was making modifications, and everything had been fine. all the sudden the database failed. I don't believe i made any database calls, in fact I'm pretty sure it randomly crashed overnight (i shut my macbook lid, went to bed, woke up, and came back, and my app had closed and "database could not be started"

```
=> Client modified -- refreshing (x6)
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.
kj@Kyles-MBP simple-todos-react % meteor run
[[[[[ ~/Desktop/myWorld/simple-todos-react ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Can't start Mongo server.                     
kj@Kyles-MBP simple-todos-react % meteor run            
[[[[[ ~/Desktop/myWorld/simple-todos-react ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Can't start Mongo server.                     
kj@Kyles-MBP simple-todos-react % meteor run
[[[[[ ~/Desktop/myWorld/simple-todos-react ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Can't start Mongo server.                     
kj@Kyles-MBP simple-todos-react % meteor run
[[[[[ ~/Desktop/myWorld/simple-todos-react ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Unexpected mongo exit code null. Restarting.  
Can't start Mongo server.                     
kj@Kyles-MBP simple-todos-react % meteor reset
Project reset.                                
kj@Kyles-MBP simple-todos-react % meteor run  
[[[[[ ~/Desktop/myWorld/simple-todos-react ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: Can you edit to include the exact error that you get?

Comment: Also obligatory "Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)." Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will need to share your code - we have no idea what *might* be happening with your code.

To get around the problem, you can run a local mongodb server, and then prefix your meteor command like this:

`MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb meteor run`

This will avoid losing data, `meteor reset` will no longer delete your data, but it won't fix the problem (which is really not normal)

Comment: I realize it's been a long time, but I'm trying a new app and i occasionally still run into the same problem. If you're still interested in helping me i can post my code. But honestly, i wouldn't even begin to know where to start with showing you the code, i wouldn't know which page you want to see.

Comment: Happy to help. Running a mongo server will stop this problem from happening. It also protects your data from being wiped when you do a `meteor reset`. You can use homebrew to install mongodb community server. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/